# Resolve Firebase build number for Jenkins build

Tags: ios, firebase, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up a Jenkins Pipeline project for everything from build, test, deploy to Firebase and TestFlight and I'm running into a problem I can't wrap my head around and would love some help.

Whenever i build a certain branch it gets uploaded to Firebase Distribution.
The branch can be, and usually is, built more than one time after the initial trigger.
I need to be able to keep the same build number for different Jenkins builds of the same branch while updating it for builds of other branches.

I've tried using the build id for tracking the build number but that quickly failed.
Is there any standard way of doing this without keeping a file full of branches and build numbers?